# Contact Images location

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, motorola-droid-x, images

Where are the contact images kept?
I have a contact image that is no longer in my gallery but it is one of my contact's avatar.  I remember taking the photo and making it the avatar.  I've went into my Google Contacts via the web but it is not there.  The contact does not have a facebook or any other type of account.  So it must be somewhere on the phone.

I have a Droid X with Gingerbread.

Answer (score 3):

The contacts is actually an app, hence as other Android apps store it's data, this app also stores in a SQLite database. Images are part of contact data and are spotted in database. It is stored in `/data/data/com.Android.providers/contacta/databases/contracts.db`

Comment: Unfortunately, Astro sees the /data folder as empty.  I am guessing these folders are not visible to the user.

Comment: At first I too was stumbled as my file explorer too didn't show, but I was pretty sure about what I was looking for. in my file explorer, I enabled to show hidden files and then I was able to see the database file. By the way, I use ES file explorer.

Comment: And you are probably rooted -- as a normal user should not be able to dive below the `/data` directory (except, as with Skype, the developer was stupid enough to fiddle with the folder permissions, making them read-write for everybody).

Answer (score 1):

What I do is simply create a separate folder in Internal Storage, which contains all my 'pics for Contacts' -- SD content always tends to change OR you change the SD card  throughout years/lengthy periods of time.  Whenever I get a new phone, I simply transfer/copy the contents of my 'pics for Contacts' folder, which is located in my Internal Storage folder, via Bluetooth to the new phone.

A SIMPLIER WAY of course would be to just start saving your Contacts in your Google account under your main account.  This way, any contact, together with its contact photo, will be saved in Google Cloud.  You stated that this does not seem to work for you.  Everytimre I buy a new phone and connect it to my main Google account during initial phone setup, my Contacts and their pics transfer onto my new phone without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found an idea. You should download program from Google Play called "Save Contact photo" then you will see all your contacts there and you can share those contact photos via Bluetooth(should have another phone for that!). And then you can see that photo in another phone's gallery, so you can easily transfer it via Facebook or Whatsapp.

Comment: A link for the app or at least the developer's name  would help. I don't see any app named "Save Contact photo" in Play Store.

Comment: And even if there were an app extracting contact photos, all it would get were thumbnails (which are stored along with the records). The original photo won't be there.