# High resolution contact pictures in Marshmallow - what is their size and where are they stored

Tags: sqlite, contact-photo

Trying to answer this question [How to backup large contact photos?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179336/131553), I wanted to compare the picture size after restore

I do see a database for contacts  , as mentioned in Narayanan's [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27385/131553) -  location hasn't changed from Gingerbread days !

`/data/data/com.Android.providers/contacta/databases/contracts.db`

**How do I see the picture and it's size ??**

I gather one has to SQLlite viewer but Apps from play store didn't help and I am new to SQL stuff. It would be nice if I can get a way of doing this (preferably without using PC but if that's inevitable , it's fine )

**Edit:**

- Android version 6.0, Rooted
- When I see `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/photos/` they pertain to WhatsApp photos not contact pictures

Comment: What Android version are we talking about? Did you already check at `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files`, if present?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: updated question

Comment: That folder can only be opened as root. Are you rooted? Furthermore, WhatsApp cannot alter it, but it may be possible that the above app makes use of the Contacts Provider, which in turn stores WhatsApp's contact thumbnails.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman of course the device is rooted, otherwise wouldn't be able to see /data/data.  Coming back to the question, maybe WhatsApp does as you suggested but I am trying to locate my contact pics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you're using an AOSP ROM, you just missed the correct answer:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/photos
```

Whatever the original size of the image is, it will be resized to 720*720 and shrinked to less than 64 KiB.

To verify this by yourself, get these commands executed in a root shell. <s>You need BusyBox or [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) for `find` and `xargs`</s> Android M introduced ToyBox which has `find` and `xargs` built in.

```
# cd /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts
# ## Add a picture of your choice to a contact
# find -type f | xargs ls -t
```

See the output. `find -type f` outputs every single file found under current working directory, and `xargs` use piped stdin as arguments to `ls -t`, which lists and sorts all files from the command line by last modification time. You will see that the top 3 files are

```
./databases/contacts2.db
./databases/contacts2.db-journal
./files/photo/3 (num. varies dpd. on your env.)
```

The answer is clear as seen above.

Comment: No need to specially spacify toybox. It is already symlinked in /system/bin

Comment: OK.. Ran those commands on Terminal Emulator and see the output as you said and the interpretation Accepting the answer +1. But my doubt remains

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834815/how-to-find-the-max-image-size-supported-for-contacts-images) supports 720 by 720 - which means this hasn't changed from Kitkat

Comment: Also while the size part is clarified , where are they stored, which is kind of incidental - if you can address that and add to your answer it would be nice

Comment: For high res images, I supposr it's handled by your Contacts frontend app, because it's not what Contacts Storage should do.

Comment: I don't have a separate front end app - use stock Moto

Comment: [Looks like an old issue and the solution is Gmail web???](https://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m7/276826-hi-res-contact-photo-how.html) [Also this.](https://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-lte/191001-higher-resolution-contact-pictures.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62144/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-ibug).